# Small pixel font

Tags: c#, fonts, bitmap, vector-graphics, led

I'm trying to display pixels on a monitor, in preparation for when I display on a set of LEDs.
I'm doing this using a font to draw onto a bitmap, and then reading off the bitmap, whether the pixel is lighter or darker, and putting this into a 2 dimensional array of booleans.
This array is then passed into my interface-specific display method, for displaying.
As this set is only going to be 6 pixels high, I'm using a font made for a six pixel resolution from www.dafont.com/6px.font
Currently this system doesn't display that well - some characters are not really readable.

Is this even the right way to be doing this? What should I be doing?
Thanks!

Pixel map file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Phidgets
{
    public class StringDrawer
    {
        internal int height, width;
        internal bool[][] mapData;
        GraphicalInterface MyGraphicalInterface;
        Bitmap canvas;
        int MaxPixelLength;
        Graphics canvasGraphics;
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Font font;
        public StringDrawer(int width, int height, GraphicalInterface myInterface)
        {
            InitFont();
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
            MaxPixelLength = 2048 + width;//2048 pixels, plus the amount of empty pixels at the end.
            mapData = new bool[height][];
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                mapData[i] = new bool[width];
            }
            MyGraphicalInterface = myInterface;
            canvas = new Bitmap(MaxPixelLength, height);
            canvasGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);
        }
        void DrawPoint(int x, int y)
        {
            mapData[x][y] = true;
        }
        void Clear()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    mapData[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        public void DrawString(String input)
        {
            input = input.ToUpper();
            Clear();
            PaintCanvas(input);
            UpdateDataFromCanvas();
            MyGraphicalInterface.Update(mapData);
        }
        public void UpdateDataFromCanvas()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapData.Count(); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < mapData[0].Length; x++)
                {
                    bool b = canvas.GetPixel(x, y).R < 128;//r g or b is equivalent here, half way between light and dark.
                    mapData[y][x] = b;
                }
            }
        }
        Bitmap GetCurrentFrame(int startX)
        {
            return null;
        }
        void PaintCanvas(String input)
        {
            canvasGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
            canvasGraphics.DrawString(input, regFont, solidBrush, 0, 0);
        }
        SolidBrush solidBrush;
        Font regFont;
        void InitFont()
        {
            System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
            privateFontCollection.AddFontFile("../../6px-Normal.ttf");
            solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            FontFamily[] fontFamilies = privateFontCollection.Families;
            string familyName = fontFamilies[0].Name;
            regFont = new Font(familyName, 6,FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
    public abstract class GraphicalInterface
    {
        public abstract void Update(bool[][] mapData);
    }
    public class ScreenInterface : GraphicalInterface
    {
        //int xStart = 350;
        //int yStart = 23;
        int xStart, yStart;
        Graphics g;
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        public ScreenInterface(int xStart, int yStart, Form1 f)
        {
            g = f.CreateGraphics();
            this.xStart = xStart;
            this.yStart = yStart;
        }
        public override void Update(bool[][] mapData)
        {
            const int scale = 4;
            for (int y = 0; y < mapData.Count(); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < mapData[0].Length; x++)
                {
                    if (mapData[y][x])
                        g.FillRectangle(brush, xStart + (x * scale), yStart + (y * scale), scale, scale);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class LedInterface : GraphicalInterface
    {
        public override void Update(bool[][] mapData)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapData.Count(); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < mapData[0].Length; x++)
                {
                    //not implemented
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form1 file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Phidgets
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        StringDrawer testDrawer, LedDrawer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int width = 24;
            const int height = 6;
            ScreenInterface screen = new ScreenInterface(450, 23, this);
            testDrawer = new StringDrawer(width, height, screen);
            LedDrawer = new StringDrawer(width, height, new LedInterface());
        }

        private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testDrawer.DrawString("a b c");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Thanks to defont.com/6px for the font used, and as always, much wow to stackoverflow.");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: If it works, no need to worry. I guess, something along the lines of what you did (drawing onto an off-screen bitmap) is a good way. Not only would it allow you to use and mix different fonts and styles (italics, bold, etc. - although, perhaps not relevant with height of 6px) rather easily, but it would also be rather easy to increase resolution for your next LED display while keeping the same fonts, if you desire so...

Comment: Cheers for your comment, the issue is that it's not really displaying well, at the moment. If I tweak the '128' value it may be a bit better or worse, but it's not really readable at the moment.

Comment: Answer is probably somewhere among http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+turn+off+antialiasing posts...

Comment: I haven't looked at the font you are using, but it might perhaps just visually look like a blocky 6px font, but in reality it might not render very well in small point sizes (i am just speculating...). Perhaps you can try the  bitmap font "Small Font Regular" (smalle.fon) which should be part of your Windows installation

Comment: Seems like [LED Font Creator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29461/Led-Font-Creator-with-Scrolling-Display) on codeproject has similarities to your question.

Comment: Figured out the problem - the font wasn't even assigning!

When I called:
    regFont = new Font(familyName, 6,FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

It didn't change! Like, if you went through in the debugger, the value didn't change after the assignment. So weird. But when I used the constructer passing just the font-family object and the size it worked. Somewhat anticlimactic, but thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem - the font wasn't even assigning!

When I called:
    regFont = new Font(familyName, 6,FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

It didn't change! Like, if you went through in the debugger, the value didn't change after the assignment. So weird. but when I changed the InitFont method to say:

```
    void InitFont()
    {
        System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection =
           new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
        privateFontCollection.AddFontFile("../../6px-Normal.ttf");
        solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        FontFamily[] fontFamilies = privateFontCollection.Families;
        regFont = new Font(fontFamilies[0], 6);
    }
```

the assignment worked.
So a little anti-climactic, but thanks guys for your help.